# TypeError: string indices must be integers ,I used items() for iteration

Tags: python, django, excel

I got an error TypeError: string indices must be integers.Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXX/testapp/app/views.py", line 164, in <module>
    user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I wrote

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/excel1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index) 
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()

files = glob.glob('./user/*.xlsx')

for x in files:
    if "$" not in x:
      book3 = xlrd.open_workbook(x)
      sheet3 = book3.sheet_by_index(0)
      cells = [
    ]
      data_dict = OrderedDict()
      for key, rowy, colx in cells:
         try:
            data_dict[key] = sheet3.cell_value(rowy, colx)
         except IndexError:
            data_dict[key] = None

      for row_number, row_data in data_dict.items():
          user1 = User.objects.filter(user_id=row_data['user_id']).exists()
          if user1:
             user1.__dict__.update(**data_dict)
             user1.save()
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens, because I know data_dict is dictionary type, so I used items() for iteration.Also I cannot understand which indices must be integers.How can I fix this?What should I write it?
data_dict is like

```
OrderedDict([('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)], [('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)], [('user_id', '1'), ('name', 'Blear'), ('nationality', 'America'), ('domitory', 'A'), ('group', 1)])
```

Comment: `row_data` appears to be a string. Can you provide a sample for `data_dict`?

Comment: It looks like you repeatedly overwrite each element of `data_dict` with a string representing a cell in a spreadsheet. So naturally it is a string when you come to use it in the following loop. Did you perhaps mean to make each element a dict, then set values to that inner dict?

Comment: @franciscosollima I added my question, if you know something please help  me

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh,really?Yes,I  mean to make each element a dict, then set values to that inner dict.So,how can I fix this?